# how to send user input data to MySQL databse using nodeJS & Ajax (no php)

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax

i am currently creating a registration form which works with a mysql database. my goal is to take the user input data and have it save onto the data base.

my current code

```
  // include mysql module
var mysql = require('mysql');

// create a connection variable with the required details
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost", //
    user: "john", // user name for mysql database
    password: "4056", // password
    database: "register" //database
});

var x = "John";
var y = "4854304";
var z ="john@gmail.com";
// make to connection to the database.
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // if connection is successful
    var records = [
        [x, y, z]

    ];
    con.query("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) VALUES ?", [records], function (err, result, fields) {
        //  error message
        if (err) throw err;
        // result
        console.log("data has been sent");
    });
});
```

the above code when run sends the pre defined variables (x,y,z) to my database and correctly displays the values but i want the variable to dynamically change based on what the user inputs. when trying to link this code using script tag to my html page. it doesnt work due to it being client side. the only examples i can find are using php which i was specifically told not to use and ive been struggling using ajax. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Node.js can run as a webserver.

Comment: i think i fundamentally misunderstand how i should be sending this data to the database. so what would happen is "user input" > ajax to node.js > node.js  to database. is that correct